# Flutter workmanager periodic task under 15 min

Tags: flutter

I am trying to set my workmanager frequency to 5 min but android minimum limit is 15 minutes.
Is it possible to pass this? Can a function be set to run for 15 minutes?

Comment: Sorry it is not possible. If you go through the documentation you will notice something like the following:

When no frequency is provided the default 15 minutes is set.
Minimum frequency is 15 min. Android will automatically change your frequency to 15 min if you have configured a lower frequency.

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin Do you know why when I set the frequency to 30 min , it doesn't repeat every 30 min , it repeats in different time like 20 min or 25 min or 1 hour .

Comment: This is because of priority set by OS. There is nothing you can do to go around it or as per my knowledge.